# Apache in Docker only shows the default Apache “It Works!” page

Tags: apache-http-server, docker

I am running an Apache HTTPD server on my Mac. My Docker compose file is located in `~/httpd` and I want my Apache server to run the files in `~/httpd/html`.

When I enter the shell for the container the `html` directory is connect. However, when checking the webpage it only gives me the default Apache “It Works!” site instead of my site.

Here are the contents of my Docker compose file.

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    web:
        image: httpd
        volumes:
            - ./html:/Users/user/httpd/html
        ports:
            - 80:80
```

Comment: Seems like your Docker container is looking for a name based virtual host for your site. That means if you attempt to access the site outside of the hostname you will get the default page. Did you set Apache configs for the Docker container such as `000-default.conf`? Look at [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24828173/117259) for more details.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 For some reason the `/etc/apache2/`or `/etc/httpd` directory does not exist.

Comment: Well, that is weird. Wonder if it is running on a default Apache config without the configs in place. Don’t have deep Docker knowledge but have deep Apache knowledge and to me, that is what I described: It’s not loading a config that would point to that path.